# Orchestrator in a pure Windows enviroment

Tags: .net, orchestration

I have a bunch of web services, web sites and worker services all running on Windows servers, all in C#. We are not using any cloud provider.

I am looking for an Orchestrator without telling our system guys to go to Linux.

Do you know what I should be looking into?

Comment: What is "an Orchestrator"?

Comment: I am looking for something like kubernetes but which run on Windows